# Multiple Bibliographies - Basic

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, multibib

I'm try to use package which provides the multiple bibliographies first time. Before, I've used just standard **thebibliography** environment.

Here is the example from **bibunits** package manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\begin{document}
\begin{bibunit}[plain]
References to the \TeX book \cite{Knuth:1991}
and to Lamport’s \LaTeX\ book, which appears
only in the references\nocite{Lamport:1994}.
\putbib[lit]
\end{bibunit}
\begin{bibunit}[alpha]
A new bibunit with a different style and a cite
of a Postscript tutorial \cite{Adobe:1985}.
\putbib[lit]
\end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I can't understand one simple thing:
where is the describe of book has been writen? 
(Donald E. Knuth. The TEX book. Addison-Wesley, Reading,
Massachusetts, 1991. and others)
In the case of the **thebibliography** environment, it was provided by **\bibitem** command inside the **thebibliography** environment, but what in the case of **bibunits** and similar packages?

Comment: Do you mean where is the information for each bibliography entry stored?  That would be in the `.bib` file, which looks like it is called `lit.bib` in your example.  If you are unfamiliar with the BibTeX format, you should consider reading [*Tame the Beast: The B to X of BibTeX*](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast).  It may be accessible on your computer already via the command `texdoc ttb`.

Comment: Dear Jon, thanks for info. Yes, I mean the information for each bibliography. I'll typeset it according BibTeX manual.

Comment: If `biblatex` is an option, it makes it a lot easier to produce multiple bibliographies than the methods available with `bibtex`. At least, so I've found.